# HLS with AES-128 - Decrypt in PHP (on the fly)

Tags: php, key, http-live-streaming

It is my playlist HLS with encrypt AES-128

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:389
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="1499283644939.key",IV=0x00000000000000000000015D1444E20B
#EXTINF:10.000,
1499283686259.ts
#EXTINF:6.400,
1499283696354.ts
[...]
```

I want decrypt this wideo on the fly (without a temporary write to disk) in PHP. This is my code decrypting the first segment of this video:

```
# Input
$video_file = file_get_contents("1499283696354.ts");
$key_value = file_get_contents("1499283644939.key");
$key_iv = "0x00000000000000000000015D1444E20B";
$key_method = "AES-128-CBC";

# Output
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="1499283696354_decrypt.ts"');

echo openssl_decrypt(
  $video_file, 
  $key_method, 
  $key_value, 
  $key_iv

);
```

The newly created video cannot be played, but saveing on the desktop, icon this video contains a screenshot of this video. I attach files with this stream (playlist and all segemnt) and my decrypt code in the link below:

http://www56.zippyshare.com/v/jCeRVJFZ/file.html

Thank you for your interest

Comment: There's no actual question.

Comment: The newly created video can not be played, lack script error. The question - why?

Comment: That screen shot only shows there is a file available for download as a .rar file. I don't see a screenshot of the video.

Comment: This link contains the files of this stream (playlist and all segments) and my code in php to decrypt first segemnt this stream (as example). The generated file by this script, saved on the desktop, icon this video contains a screenshot of this video - sorry for my bad english. Now -> segment can play in "Media Player Classic", can not play in VLC, where before by decrypting the entire stream played in VLC played from playlist.

Comment: So the problem seems to be more related to encoding rather than decrypting.

Comment: Hmm, you mean encoding a php file or a generated file video?

Comment: If your decrypted file plays in Media Player but not VLC, it's not a problem of decrypting, it's a video codex problem (that's what I meant by encoding).

Comment: It seems to me that this is not a fault of faulty video codecs in my computer, it's a bug when decrypting. I assume that there is a bug with which can play in "Media Player Classic", but cant play in VLC (and example: Kodi). I want to clearly add that before decrypting the stream can play in VLC , but after decryption it can no longer play. See this pack with files, before and after the crypt: link -> http://www107.zippyshare.com/v/QRZZI9Ae/file.html

Comment: Are you sure the video can be played in VLC BEFORE the encryption? If so, then try a byte to byte comparison of pre & post encryption.

Comment: Yes, I sure (only using playlist m3u8 - there is a uri to key, method and iv). How can I try a byte to byte comparison of pre and post encryption?

Comment: Do an MD5 checksum on both files and see if they're the same. If not, there are some text editors that you can use to compare them. There are plenty to choose from.